# Vuetify tooltip is now shown inside button inside card component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the below template (no need to put the  here for the purpose of this question):

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <v-card :color="variant">
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-tooltip top>
                    <v-btn icon slot="activator" @click="openConsole">
                        <v-icon>computer</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    <span>Console</span>
                </v-tooltip>
                <v-btn icon v-if="failed"><v-icon>bug_report</v-icon></v-btn>
                <v-btn icon @click="show = !show">
                    <v-icon>{{ show ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more' }}</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want a tooltip to be shown whenever mouse hovers on the Console Icon button.

What am I missing here?

Is there an issue with tooltip on Icons inside v-card-actions ?
I looked at this reference https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOLjVz?editors=1010 but couldn't apply it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

need to add `data-app` attribute at the root div component:

```
        <div data-app>
              <v-card :color="variant">
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-tooltip top>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                      <v-btn v-on="on" @click="openConsole" icon>
                        <v-icon>computer</v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <span>Console</span>
                  </v-tooltip>
                  <v-btn icon v-if="failed"><v-icon>bug_report</v-icon></v-btn>
                  <v-btn icon @click="show = !show">
                <v-icon>{{ show ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more' }}</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're using a newer `vuetify` version which has different syntax? Try this:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn v-on="on" @click="openConsole" icon>
      <v-icon>computer</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>Console</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Check out [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips#tooltips) for more details

Comment: @Ben what Vuetify version you're using?

Comment: version 2.1.13 with Vue 3.7.0

Comment: @Ben then my example should work. Reload the page and make sure you're hovering the correct button.

Comment: Tried that as well. no luck :(

Comment: @Ben did you reload the browser page? Check the console, are there any errors?

Comment: I do get a warning says "unable to locate target" and it's related to the tooltip